Spring data JPA native query - How to work with query parameters defined in postgresql array?
I am trying to update a jsonb column where I have a data similar to this structure:
   {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "John doe",
      "address": {
        "street": "123 street",
        "city": "new york",
        "country": "US",
        "postalcode": "123456"
      },
      "subjects": [
        {
          "subjectId": "123",
          "name": "science",
          "modules": 12
        },
        {
          "subjectId": "124",
          "name": "physics",
          "modules": 5
        }
      ]
    }

And, I am trying to update the subjects array with subjectId using the query like:
update 
    student set   student_details = 
        jsonb_set( student_details, array['subjects', elem_index::text],
            '{
          "subjectId": "123",
          "name": "science-1",
          "modules": 6
        }'::jsonb,
            true)from (
    select 
        pos- 1 as elem_index
    from 
        student, jsonb_array_elements(student->'subjects') with ordinality arr(elem, pos)
    where  id = 1 and
        elem->>'subjectId' = '123'
    ) sub
where
    id = 1;

When I execute this in the postgresql pgAdimin directly it works fine.
But, when I am trying to use this as a Spring data JPA native query, it is giving me error, which has something to do with the 'elem_index' inside the ARRAY:

Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException:
expecting CLOSE_BRACKET, found ',' near line 1, column 83 [UPDATE
student SET  student_details = jsonb_set(student_details,
ARRAY['subjects', cast(elem_index as text)],    cast(:subject as jsonb),
false) FROM (    SELECT         pos- 1 as elem_index    FROM
student, jsonb_array_elements(student_details -> 'subjects') WITH
ordinality arr(elem, pos)    WHERE id = :studentId AND
elem->>'subjectId' = :subjectId    ) SUB WHERE    id = :studentId]

The Native query looks like this in the respository:
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query(value = "UPDATE student " +
        "SET  student_details = jsonb_set(" +
        "student_details, ARRAY['subjects', cast(elem_index as text)]," +
        "    cast(:subject as jsonb), false" +
        ") " +
        "FROM (" +
        "    SELECT " +
        "        pos- 1 as elem_index" +
        "    FROM " +
        "        student, jsonb_array_elements(" +
        "student_details -> 'subjects'" +
        ") WITH ordinality arr(elem, pos)" +
        "    WHERE id = :studentId" +
        " AND" +
        "        elem->>'subjectId' = :subjectId" +
        "    ) SUB" +
        " WHERE" +
        "    id = :studentId")
Integer updateStudentDetailsSubjects(@Param("studentId") String studentId, @Param("subjectId") String subjectId, @Param("subject") String subject);

Am I missing something?

In your case, I would recommend you to check if there are proper spaces between concatenated strings to avoid syntax errors.
I see that in your sql query, after pos- 1 as elem_index, there doesn't seem to be a space before FROM. You should a space there to separate the clauses properly.
Also, you should be sure whether the placeholders for parameters (:studentId, :subjectId, :subject) were correctly positioned and replaced with the actual parameter values during query execution.
